# How can install a Hindi font in Android 2.1?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, localization, fonts

I have a Samsung Galaxy S GT-i9000 and I want to install a Hindi font on it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There's NO support for Hindi or any other Indian languages built-in, in all Android versions up to and including FroYo (2.2). Gingerbread (2.3) does support Hindi as a language according to [this post](http://androidos.in/2010/12/android-2-3-brings-more-languages-support-incl-hindi/)

If you're looking for a Hindi keyboard, you'll need the HindiIME APK from Samsung - they're usually installed on phones that Samsung sells in India. As a workaround, use Opera Mini for Android - it renders Unicode Devanagiri fonts correctly.

Comment: Actually i have some sms in Hindi font which i cant read, so how to read them

Comment: @Jeevan The new [Google Translate](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate) has a feature to translate SMS.  I haven't tried it myself but I did notice there was Hindi available.  You may want to try that.

Once you open the app at the bottom left there should be the option for "SMS Translation".  From here you can select the correct message to translate.

Hope this helps

Comment: Your suggestions in last paragraph are pointless as there's no system font installed.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - are you referring to my answer? At the time of writing it, the Galaxy I7500 and the Galaxy Spica did indeed have Hindi keyboards.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately SAMSUNG has not installed Hindi font on the Indian variant of the Galaxy S. But there is a workaround. For this you will need root access. You can replace the DroidSansFallback.ttf file which is located in /system/fonts/ on your phone with the font mentioned in the first post of this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=798380.

Restart and enjoy. :)

Answer (score 1):

[This XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=16066606#post16066606) has instructions, summarized below:

1. Install [HinKhoj Dictionary](https://market.android.com/details?id=HinKhoj.Dictionary) and then [Go SMS Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gosms).
2. Open Go SMS, go to "Appearance Settings"

   1. Hit "Scan Fonts Packages"
   2. Go to "Conv. List Customization" from "Conversation List appearance", choose "Time and message font" and select "Hindi Hinkhoj Dictionary". It will automatically choose the "Mangal" font.
   3. Press the back button 3 times and choose to save the settings.
   4. Now go to "Conversation Customization" from "Conversation appearance" and change "Incoming font" and "Outgoing font" the same as above, and save this setting with different name.
   5. Finally from both of "Conversation List appearance" and "Conversation appearance" apply the User Defined Settings as your saved name.
3. Exit the application and reboot your phone.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted Android does not support Hindi (or any other language that requires Complext Text Layouts, except for Arabic). Here is the relevant bug post for Hindi on GingerBread:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12981

You can achieve some form of readability by installing a Hindi font, but it will not shape properly. If you can't live with that, than you will need to install third party apps that support Hindi. That said, the Galaxy 5 and Galaxy 3 sold in India (the Indian Variant) does have support for Hindi, but not the Galaxy S! Bug Samsung about it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install fonts, if you want Hindi to browse Hindi websites.

Use SETT Hindi Browser: https://market.android.com/details?id=lk.bhasha.sett.hindi

It's an exclusive browser for Hindi & it displays Hindi well in any device having Android 2.2 or above.