# Is there a browser that will display Armenian letters?

Tags: browser, localization, browser-add-ons

I have just got a an HTC Desire as a present and I want to view [www.mathnet.am](http://www.mathnet.am) which is an Armenian site. But insted of Armenian letters I see squares. I have read some advices in some forums, but could not solve the problem. Please help.

By the way I can't see www.Google.am (this is the Armenian variant of it) letters too. The same squares :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link, where that kind of browser (Hay Web Browser) can be downloaded: http://webdroid.life.am/
Here is the facbook group, where Hay Web Browser is being discussed, and the creator can answer to your questions: http://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=group_191625270874191&ap=1

Answer (score 1):

I've tried visiting both those sites in a few browsers, and see the same problem with the square boxes rather than letters. It looks like this probably isn't a problem with the browser(s) but more that the fonts being used to show the sites in the browser don't have all the necessary characters.

Are you able to see Armenian letters in emails or text messages at all?

There was a previous question about [installing Hindi fonts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/how-to-install-hindi-font-in-android-2-1), that no one's come up with an answer for yet. Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) does add support for more languages, but unfortunately Armenian doesn't seem to be one of them.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to update your OS version into latest - that's all you need to do.

Comment: Have you done this with this device? Does the OS update include Armenian language files?