# How to install Regional fonts in Sony Xperia Dual M

Tags: fonts

How can I install punjabi fonts in my andriod phone? I have a Sony Xperia Dual M.

Comment: At least related: [How to make an Android device to display complex rendering of Indic characters?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25359/16575) / [How can I install custom fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11789/16575) / [How can install a Hindi font in Android 2.1?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4213/16575) / and many more. You can find such questions e.g. by hitting the tag you've used: [fonts](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:*
**You have to root your phone. I'm not responsible for any damage done to your phone**.

Step 1: Root your phone

Step 2: Download [SansFallBack.zip](https://www.sendspace.com/file/1qwuka)

Step 3: Install any [Root File manager](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root%20file%20manager&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiEwoRcm9vdCBmaWxlIG1hbmFnZXJ6AhgAigECCAE%3D%3AS%3AANO1ljK-7jE&hl=en).

Step 4: Open File manager and the zip file to `/System/Fonts`, (Also backup the original file)

(Optional) Step 5: Change the permissions of corresponding folder and files, If any error occurs during installation