# Add a new laguage (Bengali) in my Huawei Honor 3C phone not having this language

Tags: languages

How to add a new language "Bengali of India" in my Huawei Honor 3C phone not having this language.

I have checked SETTINGS -> Language / Input and my language is not listed here.

I saw Samsung Phones has Bengali Language in Languages List as I have Samsung Tab311.

So how to add this new language in my honor 3C Android Phone 4.2.2 JellyBeans

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83503

Answer (score 1):

Bengali is only available as a system language starting with Android 5.0.0 Lollipop. So you can't add it as a  system language ( I don't know about options with root). However, you can configure Bengali input using a custom keyboard option such as [Google Keyboard](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjAqK631ZbIAhXCjo4KHU-6CTo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.google.android.inputmethod.latin%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNHTHzUvXnmZ3ZGjvaK4Y7C5YTEfsA&sig2=Xee_9s30gF19f_DX0iSFmw&bvm=bv.103388427,d.c2E) or [Swiftkey Keyboard](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjHxbrN1ZbIAhVEcY4KHUAyDiE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.touchtype.swiftkey%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNGdDQMGMnBTaOsRLdgfNbD79_ig2A&sig2=onxDDmw-T_ObzlKOZsco8Q&bvm=bv.103388427,d.c2E). These have a "Languages" option for adding languages.